# Vuejs add dynamic table row based on searchkey

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hello i'm new to vuejs just got the basic ideas, can somebody help me on this regard writing the addItems method (or provide similar resource) based on searchKey and click on item to add into table row, as well as the removeitem method, my humble thanks in advance .

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      const vueApp = new Vue({
         el: '#myApp',
         data: {
               items: ['apple','banana','orange'],
               searchKey:'',
               rowItems: []
            },
         methods: {
            searchItem: function(){
            },
            addItems: function(){
            },
            removeItems: function(){
            }
         }
      });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="myApp">

<input type="text" name="search" v-model='searchKey' @click='searchItem'>

<table id="items">
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish your task, you need

**1)** a list of possible items to select

**2)** a search term to narrow down the former list

**3)** a list of items you selected

The `select` function has to operate on the items of **2**.

The `remove` function has to operate on the items of **3**

A possible *naive* implementation looks like

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    searchTerm: "",
    searchItems: ["apples","bananas"],
    selected: []
  },
  methods: {
    select(item){
        this.selected.push(item);
    }
  },
  computed:{
    selectedItems(){
        return this.selected.join(", ")
    },
    matches(){
      if(!this.searchTerm) return;
        return this.searchItems.filter(sI=>sI.includes(this.searchTerm));
    }
  }
})
```

This should point you in the direction to go.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3f0xr2k/)

Comment: I forgot to thank you man.
really appreciate  the help you did :)

Comment: @MilonHossain Perhaps, you also may accept the answer ;)